# Does azure-communication-calling android sdk support external cameras?

Tags: android, azure, azure-android-sdk

Does  azure-communication-calling android sdk support external cameras?

Answer (score 0):

*Yes, as per the below available features SDK supports external camera's.*

*Here are the features available for ACS SDK video caling.*

> #### Features available

> - Place and receive 1-1 audio/video call
> - Place and receive 1-N (group) audio/video call
> - Join (1-N) group audio/video call
> - Escalate a 1-1 call to a group call - by adding voip participant
> - Dial-out to another voip participant to join an ongoing group audio/video call
> - Preview local video camera
> - Share local video camera stream
> - Render video from participants
> - Render screenshare from participants
> - List audio/video devices
> - Mid-call operations (Mute/Unmute)
> - Mid-call operations (Turn Video on/Turn Video off)
> - Mid-call operations (Switch between Video devices)
> - Mid-call operations (Add/Remove participant to/from the ongoing audio/video call)
> - Push notification support for incoming audio/video call
> - Place a call to PSTN participant
> - Test your mic, speaker, and camera via audio testing service (available by calling 8:echo123)

*For latest releases and Bug fixes you can check this [document](https://github.com/Azure/Communication/blob/master/releasenotes/acs-calling-android-sdk-release-notes.md#features-available) and for complete overview check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/communication-services/concepts/best-practices).*

Comment: My Android device doesn't have a built-in camera, and I still can't turn on the camera after connecting to an external camera

Comment: Check out if there is any version issues

Comment: com.azure.android:azure-communication-calling 2.2.0